# How to change the net-snmp default port to one less than 1024 in linux?

Tags: linux, port, net-snmp

Everyone!
In Red Hat Server Linux, I change the Net-SNMP default port(161) to 165 by adding "agentaddress 165" in snmpd.conf file, but it doesn't work. Service snmpd startting failed. 
Is anybody knowing the reason?

Answer (score 0):

1. close SELinux.
2. add "agentaddress XXX(port)" in config file /etc/snmpd.conf.
3. service snmpd restart, check the running status of the snmp.